# Plot of interpolation

Tags: plot, octave, interpolation

Problem: I have a working Lagrange interpolation script

```
x0 = [-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3];
y0 = [-15 1 5 3 1 5 21]; 
x=-1.65;

function y = lagrange(x, x0, y0)

n = length(x0); 
y = 0;

  for i=1:n
      p = 1;
      for j=1:n
          if j == i
              continue;
          endif;
          p *= (x-x0(j)) / (x0(i)-x0(j));
      endfor;
      y += y0(i) * p;   
  endfor;

endfunction

y = lagrange(x, x0, y0);
```

but I need to draw a graph of these values on a smooth curve (linspace probably).
Prerequisite: I cannot use the built-in "polyfit" function.
Do I need to specify a vector with 100 values to build a similar chart?

Comment: Why not loop over the function through multiple `x` values (with `linspace`, colon arrays or whatever you want to use), store that in an array and plot the array?

Comment: @Adriaan I thought exactly the same, so far with little effect. Im pretty new in octave.